# MFC IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE with template

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there any way to use `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` with a template class? If not, why not? Is there another solution to this?

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class A : public B{
public:
A(){ printf("A constuctor "); }
void fn( ){ T* a = new T(); }
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(A<CObject>, B);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've taken a quick look at the macros and thrown together a completely un tested macro that may work.

```
#define _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name, template_name) ((CRuntimeClass*)(&class_name<template_name>::class##class_name##template_name))
#define RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name, template_name) _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name, template_name)

#define _IMPLEMENT_RUNTIMECLASS( class_name, template_name, base_class_name, wSchema, pfnNew, class_init ) \
                                 AFX_COMDAT CRuntimeClass class_name<template_name>::class##class_name##template_name = { \
                                 #class_name, sizeof(class class_name<template_name>), wSchema, pfnNew, \
                                 RUNTIME_CLASS(base_class_name), NULL, class_init }; \
                                 CRuntimeClass* class_name<template_class::GetRuntimeClass() const \
                                 { return RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name, template_name); }

#define IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE( class_name, template_name, base_class_name ) \
                             CObject* PASCAL class_name<template_name>::CreateObject() \
                             { return new class_name<template_name>; } \
                             IMPLEMENT_RUNTIMECLASS(class_name, template_name, base_class_name, 0xFFFF, \
                             class_name<template_name>::CreateObject, NULL)
```

Then you can call:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE( A, CObject, B);
```

Give it a try, as i say, it may work :D

Answer (score 0):

Basically Visual studio 2005 supports template runtime class, but Microsoft took the macros out since visual studio 2010(or 2008).

**Solution:** copy the template class runtime macros out from the `afx.h` of visual studio 2005, and make a `.h` file of yours.